# date function to get last months data

Tags: sql, oracle, date

The application can call the stored procedure any day of the current month, or any day of the next month to get the current month data. It is passing in a date parameter (in_month). I have the following sql as part of the procedure:

```
SELECT nvl(to_char(count(tlof_cnlofrid)), 'NA')
from service.kndtlof
where tlof_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu
and tlof_cnservic = texe_cnfuncid
and tlof_cnsubser = texe_cnsubser
and tlof_cnfhalta > trunc(to_date(IN_MONTH), 'mm') 
and tlof_cnfhalta < trunc(sysdate,'mm');
```

The above would get me the desired result if run the following month. But what if they want data on the 15th of the current month? Is there a way to tell the last part of the query to look for something like the equal to or less than the last day of the month that is passed in the parameter? The in_month parameter is sent in the format "DD-MON-YY".
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are asking for last month's data and again you wrote 15th of current month. So exactly which one you want?

Comment: Please show example data and expected output. This is not clear.

Comment: A `date` does not have a format strings have a format.  My assumption is that `in_month` is a `date` and not a `varchar2` in a specific format.  I am not sure that I understand what you want.  If I pass in `date '2016-09-02'`, do you want the expression to evaluate to `date '2016-09-01'` or `date '2016-08-01'`?  Or would you want it to evaluate differently based on the current date?

Comment: I totally agree with @OldProgrammer, example data and output would clarify things ... otherwise the description is too vague..

Comment: Hi Justin, the date gets sent in as a varchar. The SP is to collect information for a specific month, as is passed in that parameter. If that param sends in '01-AUG-16' OR '15-AUG-16' it will get data for August. To get that August data, this procedure can be run either in August, lets say the 15th to collect everything from the 1st to the 15th, on August 31st to collect the whole months data, or lets say on September 2 to collect Augusts data. The code i have put works if it is run on September 2, but it would not work when run in the month of August itself, since the last line is sysdate.

Comment: Why don't you use `ADD_MONTHS(trunc(to_date(IN_MONTH), 'mm') ,1)` instead of `sysdate`?

Comment: why not just pass in a date range (begin date, end date)?

Comment: So `in_month` is a `varchar2`?  If so, that's a poor design decision.  If you are stuck with a parameter of the wrong data type, your `to_date` call should have an explicit format mask.  I still don't understand what behavior you want.  If you pass in "01-AUG-16", you want August data.  If you pass in "01-SEP-16", do you want August or September data?  If you want "01-SEP-16" to return August data, why wouldn't "01-AUG-16" return prior month data (July)?  Does the behavior depend on the current date?